# Print out the length of the name if it is more than 10 and less than 20 characters long, and the third letter in the name

Tags: java, arrays

Could anyone please help me solve this code, I keep getting error.
My main concern how to print these line out  "Print out the length of the name if it is more than 10 and less than 20 characters long, and the third letter in the name"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Class activity");

    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.out);
    System.out.println("Please enter your name");
    String name = scn.nextDouble();
    Main.processName(name);
}

/**
 * Print out the length of the name if it is more than 10 and less than 20 characters long, and the third letter in the name
 */
private int processname(String name) {
    int len = name.len();
    if (len > 10 | len < 20) {
        System.out.println("Wow," + name + " that name is between 10 and 20 characters long!");
    }
    char thirdLetter = name.charAt(3);
    System.out.println("Your name has " + len + " letters and the second letter is " + thirdLetter);
}
```

Comment: Logical or is ||, not |.

Answer (score 0):

1)You used OR instead of AND in the length clause.

2) That alone is no error, you just get everything that has the length 0 - 20. But the error is that logical OR is || and not |. Similarly logical AND is &&.

3) Besides, the third character in a string is charAt(2), not charAt(3). First character has the index 0.